# Page Transitions without Reload using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, web

So I have searched a while, and I think I have found my answer but I am not sure exactly HOW to apply it.

My problem is this: I have a website that has a menu (the site is coded in PHP and HTML5), and each menu item links to another page. The way the page works is:

```
http://domainhere/index.php#home
http://domainhere/index.php#about
http://domainhere/index.php#contact
```

etcetera...

As of now, the webpage is NOT ideal because if a user wants to directly link to the about page, the index.php#home page will load. What I want is a function that when the document load the address, it can read the value after the hashtag and load the appropriate content inside the #content div container I wrote. As of now, I have jQuery functions using animations and show()/hide() to hide the divs for each of the pages. In addition, my home page has a different format than the rest of the pages, and it requires an animation to reduce the header size. I have read into this and a lot of the solutions came up with AJAX, but I am not certain how I could apply this. Any heads up on a starter would be great, and I will continue grinding away!

Thanks

Comment: Nice summary of state handling via the URL in modern web apps:  https://github.com/balupton/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question right,you can do something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var target = location.hash;

   // Code to hide all section

   // Show the section/div whose is placed on url
   $(target).show('fast');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for reading the hashtag and responding to it is as follows, using jQuery.

The jQuery plugin I use: jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js, found at: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

I setup the hash change function to happen on page load, and on hash change. So, instead of calling your show/hide functions from the menu click, you only put them in the hash change function and let it handle both page load and menu selection. Your menu links then, only need to be concerned with changing the hash.

And, if you eventually switch to using AJAX to load your page content separately, rather than the whole site in one swoop, then the function calls in the switch can make the ajax call to return the specific content. Or, you can pass the hashtag to a generic ajax call, and the ajax web method/service call can determine which content to return based on the hashtag passed.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).hashchange(function () {
        var hash = location.hash;

        //This part here untested - you'll need to write it custom for your menu.
        switch (hash){
          case "#about":
              ShowAboutDiv(); 
              //this should be the function you already call to show the about div.
              break;
          case "#contact":
              ShowContactDiv();
              break;
          default :
              //show home div, or maybe it already shows.
              break;
        };
    });


    //handle page load hash...
    $(window).hashchange();
});
```